# How to add fields from a table to the result of SELECT to create a new view?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: p07TABLE and p07TABLE_02. The structure of them is shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS p07TABLE (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    dev_id varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    b_level varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    trig varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    t_stamp datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    a_sent varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    a_stamp datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS p07TABLE_02 (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    dev_id varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    dev_location varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    t_channel varchar(50) NOT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Note, dev_id is used as the key to link the 2 tables.

I use the SQL below to find the latest record for each dev_id in p07TABLE and it works as expected.

```
SELECT * FROM p07TABLE WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM p07TABLE GROUP by dev_id);
```

Could someone share some idea on how to create a view by adding `dev_location` and `t_channel` from `p07TABLE_02` 
to the result created by the above SQL? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
create view t_viewname as
  SELECT a.*,dev_location,t_channel
  FROM p07TABLE a inner join p07TABLE_02 b on a.dev_id=b.dev_id
  WHERE a.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM p07TABLE a1 where a.dev_id=a1.dev_id)
```

Comment: Thanks! It does join the 2 tables; however, the result contains all the entries in p07TABLE instead of just 1 entry for each dev_id (there are multiple entries for each dev_id in p07TABLE and I want the view to contain only the latest entry for each dev_id.

Comment: Thanks! I got the error - "#1052 - Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous". However, if I change the query to 

`**create view t_viewname as
  SELECT a.*,dev_location,t_channel
  FROM p07TABLE a inner join p07TABLE_02 b on a.dev_id=b.dev_id
  WHERE a.id IN (SELECT MAX(a.id) FROM p07TABLE a1 where a.dev_id=a1.dev_id)**`

I will get all the entries in p07TABLE in the view.

Comment: @WHHuang, yes, I've also changed that - you need to use the alias name where a.id in ()...

Answer (score 0):

```
create view view_name as
select * from     
(
SELECT t1.*,t2.dev_location,t2.t_channel,
row_number() over(partition by t1.dev_id order by t1.id desc) rn
  FROM p07TABLE
t1 join p07TABLE_02 t2 on t1.dev_id=t2.dev_id
 ) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: I am using mysql version 15.1. It doesn't work. Error Message "#1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause".